# libQCAR.so and libExtensionVuforia.so can't be read or are not good zip files

Tags: android, wikitude

I use Wikitude to make augmented reality, except that eclipse (on windows) can not read files libQCAR.so and libExtensionVuforia.so or they are not good zip files.

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

The .so files are library files and not meant to be opened.

In your eclipse project in your 'libs' folder add a folder called 'armeabi' (without quote marks) and add the .so files in there.